# Error in output of dynamically initialized 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a school project written in c++. I am trying to generate an array of rgb colours based on user input, for a program that generates fractals(irrelevant).

I found the need to use a pointer to a 2D array. The pointer has a global scope because it needs to be accessed across multiple files, in multiple functions.

There is no problem with the declaration of the pointer. It is as such:

in "global.h"

```
int **ptr;
int palette[10][3];
//all the statements like #ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED, etc are present
```

in  main.cpp

```
extern int **ptr;
extern int palette[10][3]; 
void gen_array();
int main()
{
     //initialize values of palette
     //palette is basically list of colors that the user selects for the 
     //desired blend of colors to appear on the screen

     gen_array();
}
```

in void gen_array(), in main.cpp

```
void gen_array()
{
    int i=0, size=0, size_arr=0;
    //size is a variable helpful in calculating "size_arr", which is the size of the dynamic array to be initialized

    while(palette[i][0]!=256)
    { //calculates "size" }

    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
       //to find "size_arr"
    }

    ptr= new int*[size_arr]();
    for(int i = 0; i < size_arr; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = new int[3];
    }

    //the following piece of code enter's values column-wise into the array

    int s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
        {
            int x=-1, a=0, b=0;

            a= palette[i][k] - palette[i+1][k];
            b= palette[i][k];
            if(a<0)
            {
                a= -a;
                x=1;
            }
            for(int j=0; j<=a; j++, s++)
            {
                ptr[i][k] = b;
                //cout<<*(*(ptr+i)+k)<<' ';
                b= b+ x;
            }
            b= b-x;

            for(int j=a+1; j<=diff[i]; j++, s++)
            {
                ptr[i][k] = b;
                cout<<ptr[i][k]<<' ';
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    //this output's the array that the pointer points to, on the screen
    for(int i=0; i<size_arr; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout<<ptr[i][j]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the data is getting generated and inputted in the array correctly [in the second-last for loop], but when outputting it [the last for loop] I'm getting junk values.

The data inputted [the correct values] as obtained from the cout statements [that are now commented] is  [this](http://pastebin.com/WunJfvzb) [printed column-wise] whereas the O/P given out is [this](http://pastebin.com/pQaYtcTf) [printed row-wise].

If it is required to be know, "size" (in this case) =2, size_arr=256 and palette[0]={0, 0, 255} and palette[1]={0,255,0}.

Can anybody point out what the problem is, and whether it has something to do with the pointer initialization?

Comment: The posted code does not compile. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `while(palette[i][0]!=256)`  The `i` is uninitialized.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -it's done in int main()

Comment: @Sh.A *It's done in int main()* -- No it isn't.  That `i` is a local variable in `gen_array`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I changed it [my bad]. I had made a mistake while posting the question.

Comment: @Sh.A `*(*(ptr+i)+k) = b;`  This is the same as `ptr[i][k] = b;`, thus the latter is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without reading all the program code like

```
for(int j=0; j<=a; j++, s++)
{
    ptr[i][k] = b;
    //cout<<*(*(ptr+i)+k)<<' ';
    b= b+ x;
}
```

looks clearly wrong. At each iteration you are writing to `ptr[i][k]` and the loop doesn't change `ptr`, `i` or `k`. This means that it will keep writing to the very same location during the loop.

Comment: Yes, it had to be `s` instead of `i` [ `k` remains as it is], and then I needed just 2 more pieces of code to get it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your int i in the loop you're using to fill int** ptr. If size = 2 then you're never going to advance ptr far enough to fill the array. Consider filling the array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size_arr; ++i){//for every pixel in the main array
  for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k){//for every subpixel
    int my_value = ...;//calculate the value for this entry
    *(*(ptr+i)+k) = my_value;//assign
```

Better yet, use a struct named pixel containing Uint8 r,g,b and allocate as pixel* ptr = new pixel[size] and iterate over pixels and assign ptr[i].r ptr[i].g ptr[i].b

Comment: `i=0; i<1; i++` ; the loop runs once, which is precisely the number of times it needs to run to fill in the details. And doing `i<size_arr` will not perform the required action.

Comment: You are not iterating over every element in your array. Look at how you index into the array when you assign values. `*(*(ptr+i)+k)` if i is 1 or 2, how are you ever traversing the entire array? You need to go over every single pointer that you allocated in  `ptr= new int*[size_arr];` and then go over every single allocation for those from:     for(int i = 0; i < size_arr; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = new int[3];
    }